# REACTJS - want to play 20 videos at a time without buffer on hover

Tags: reactjs

I had compressed all videos in handbrake and uploaded them in s3 bucket and accessing through C]loudfront but I'm still struggling with the buffering issues. so can anyone suggest me what to use next to reduce buffering.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all your videos on reducer and when the API calls, you can easily retrieve all the videos.

Hope it works for you...

Comment: Are you telling to use redux.